# How to write MySQL select query connecting two rows?

Tags: mysql, select

My Table structure is given below

```
               id    user_name    item    brand

                1       A         car    ferrari
                2       A         bike   suzuki 
                3       B         car    ferrari
                4       B         bike   yamaha
```

Here I want to write a select query for user_name having car ferrari and bike suzuki. Please help me to write sql Query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
SELECT T1.user_name
FROM MyTable T1
  LEFT JOIN MyTable T2 ON T1.id = T2.id AND T2.item = 'bike' AND T2.brand = 'suzuki'
WHERE T1.item = 'car' AND T1.brand = 'ferrari'
```

However you should consider to improve your database schema (store `vehicles` in another table, and have a relational table `users_vehicles` maybe)